# How to prove that the sequence $f_n=\frac{\cos^2(n)+4}{n+4}$ does not converge to 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I understand that I need to prove the negation of the definition for convergence, that is, $\exists \epsilon > 0\ \forall M \in \mathbb{N}\ \exists n>M |f_n-1| \geq \epsilon$ but I'm unsure on how to proceed.
The problems I've been exposed to have had $(-1)^n$ in there somewhere. In these cases I can pick an n that is odd or even so that the expression simplifies but I have no idea how to do that here.

Comment: It’s an exercise to prove with $\epsilon-\delta$ that it **doesn’t** converge to $1.$ @mathworker21

Comment: I think this is simpler than your $(-1)^n$ examples, because $f_n$ is always less than $1$ so you are not having to worry about signs. Can you find an $N$ for $\epsilon =\frac 12$?

Comment: You don't have any $(-1)^n$ in the problem since neither $\cos(n)$ nor $\cos(2n)$ can be equal to $(-1)$ for $ n \in \mathbb N $

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos(n)^2 \le 1$ we have  $\frac{\cos(n)^2+4}{n+4}\le \frac{5}{n+4} \lt 1$ for $n \gt 1$ showing that the limit is $0$.

**Discussion**

Just a little excursion.

Since $\cos(n)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+ \cos(2n) \right)$ we have $a_n = \frac{\cos(n)^2+4}{n+4} = \frac{9+\cos(2n)}{2n+8}$. This is the sum of a continiously decreasing term $d_n = \frac{9}{2n+8}$ and an oscillating term $o_n = \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n+8}$.

By the Leibniz criterion the infinite sum over $o_n$ converges. In fact the limit can be shown to be

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty o_n = \\ \frac{1}{12} \left(-2 \cos(2)+3 \pi  \sin(8)\\-3  \left(\cos(4)+2 \cos(6)+\cos(8) \log\left(4 \sin(1)^2\right)+2 \sin(8)\right)\right)\\ \simeq 0.0729141...$$

The finite sum over $d_n$ is given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^m d_n = -\frac{33}{4} + \frac{9}{2} H_{4 m}$$

where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k}$ is the harmonic number.

The infinite sum over $d_n$ hence is logarithmically divergent.

Answer (score 0):

You have that for every $$ n \in \mathbb N $$  it is
$$
0 < \frac{{\cos ^2 n + 4}}
{{n + 4}} \leqslant \frac{5}
{{n + 4}} < \frac{5}
{n}
$$
Since the sequence
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{5}
{n} = 0
$$
you have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\cos ^2 n + 4}}
{{n + 4}} = 0
$$
by comparison theorem. Since the limit, if it exists, is unique your sequence does not converge to 1.

Comment: Your statement is the opposite of what you have proved. And there's a little typo in the denominator ;-)

Comment: Thaks to let me know my typos and to avoid down vote!

Comment: My plaesure (my typo here is intended) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geq 2$, we have that $0\leq \cos^2(n)\leq 1$, and
$$|f_n-1|=\left|\frac{\cos^2(n)+4}{n+4}-1\right|=\frac{|\cos^2(n)-n|}{n+4}\geq \frac{n-1}{n+4}=1-\frac{5}{n+4}\geq \frac{1}{6}.$$
It follows that in the negation of the definition for convergence, we may take $\epsilon=1/6>0$.